# dimension of a subspace $f(n)=0$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

$V$ is a linear space of all real functions from zero to infinity of one variable. $L$ is the subspace and functions from $L$ has the following property: $f(n)=0$ for all natural $n$. I am confused  to find the dimension of set $L$.
My suggestion is infinite-dimension as there are infinite number of such functions. Am I right? Another guess is $1$.

Answer (score 0):

That would depend on the domain of the functions, if the domain is just $\mathbb N$ then the only function is $f(n)=0$. If it's domain $\mathbb R^+$ you would need to consider other possible constraints.

That there is infinite number of function is by itself not a criterion for infinite dimensionality. Take for example $\mathbb R$ which has infinite number of elements. What you need is to see that there is a collection of infinite number of **independent** functions.

If the functions are $\mathbb R^+\to\mathbb R^+$, but no other constraints you could use:

$$f_\xi(x) = \begin{cases}
1 & \text{ if } x = \xi \\
0 & \text{ otherwise}
\end{cases}$$

then the collection $f_\xi$ where $\xi\in\mathbb R^+\setminus\mathbb N$ would be an infinite collection of functions, but they are linearily independent which is easy to see.

Note that an collection being linearly independent means that a **finite** linear combination can't be zero unless all the weights are zero. That is there's no infinite sum or limit involved in any way.